# Некорректно отображает размер торрент-файла после парсинга сайта

Tags: c#, строки, парсер, torrent

Здравствуйте. Сделал парсер, который получает содержимое блока и преобразует его в текст. Затем выбрал из этого текста интересующие меня поля, одним из которых стал "размер".

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = true, AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate })
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://rutor.is/") })
                {
                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument HD = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    HD.LoadHtml(client.GetStringAsync("/torrent/496895/fizruk-03x01-05-iz-20-2016-satrip").Result); //можно делать все асинхронно. 
                    var element = HD.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='details']");//искомый элемент
                    richTextBox1.Text = element.InnerText;
                }

            }

            richTextBox1.SaveFile("file.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

            string text = File.ReadAllText("file.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
            Encoding ascii = Encoding.UTF8;
            Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

            string[] lines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i<lines.Length; i++)
            {
                this.richTextBox1.Text += lines[i] + "\n";
            }

            richTextBox1.SaveFile("file.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default, false);
            string format_prim = "Формат:";
            string reziser_prim = "Режиссер:";
            string strana_prim = "Страна:";
            string size_prim = "Разме";
            string line = "";

            string format = "";
            string reziser = "";
            string strana = "";
            string size = "";

            int formnatLenght = format_prim.Length;
            int reziserLenght = reziser_prim.Length;
            int stranaLenght = strana_prim.Length;
            int sizeLenght = size_prim.Length;


            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                if (line.Contains(format_prim))
                {

                    format = line.Substring(formnatLenght + 1);

                }

                if (line.Contains(reziser_prim))
                {

                    reziser = line.Substring(reziserLenght + 1);

                }

                if (line.Contains(strana_prim))
                {

                    strana = line.Substring(stranaLenght + 1);

                }

                if (line.Contains(size_prim))
                {

                    size = line.Substring(sizeLenght + 1);

                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show(format);
            MessageBox.Show(reziser);
            MessageBox.Show(strana);
            MessageBox.Show(size);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Итак, поле "размер" получается в виде "Размер 1.40 GB  (1500499968 Bytes)", что не дает мне его обработать. Может кто-нибудь подсказать как можно получить вот эти 1.40 GB без всего остального?

Comment: Ну и набежало же любителей сграбить контент с рутора. Если у сайта есть API, работайте через него. Если у сайта нету API, он не хочет, чтобы с него собирали информацию, и вы не заслуживаете никакой симпатии.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var full="Размер 1.40 GB (1500499968 Bytes)";
 var size = fullsize.Split(new string[] { "Размер", "(" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
```

Split делит строку на заданным сепараторам. В данном случаи это "Размер" и "(".
На выходи получаем массив строк. У нас это "1.40 GB" и 1500499968 Bytes).
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries говорит убирать пустые строки полученные при разделении. [0]-выбирает первый элемент массив - 1.40 GB.

Comment: Ваш вариант не подходит, т.к. он в итоге выдает мне слово "Название". В файле поле "размер" на этот раз выглядит так: Размер4.84&nbsp;GB  (5196844997 Bytes)

Comment: @АндрейФедоров В вашем примере исходная строка "Размер 1.40 GB (1500499968 Bytes)", я не вижу там слова "Название".Вы просите на выходите получить 1.40 GB мой пример это делает. . А &nbsp это символ пробела.

Comment: Парсер, после обработки страницы сайта, получает следующий текст: http://shortText.com/77207ea2  (сюда его не копировал, т.к. не влезает весь). Вся загвоздка может быть в том, что в MediaInfo слово "размер" повторяется ещё несколько раз. И, вполне может быть, ваш код выбирает его именно оттуда.  Мне же необходимо получить размер из поля "размер", который находится в самом низу. Может есть какой-нибудь другой способ получить содержимое той строки?

Comment: @АндрейФедоров вы задали конкретный вопрос, я дал на него ответ. Если хотите еще что-то спросить создавайте новый вопрос. Ваша ссылка не открывается. Я не знаю какие данные у вас на входе и структуру Html, что вы парсите. Могу только посоветовать посмотреть на [CsQuery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery/). Работает на селекторах CSS. Если вы знаете HTML и Css легко разберетесь.